# To-Do list remove button doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, json, class, local-storage

Can smb help me with my "to-do list", I miss smth and don't understand what it is, my delete button works fine, but after reloading page it stops working.
here HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="to-do-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-header">
        <h1 id="header">To-Do List</h1>
        <input type="text" id="input-task">
        <button id="add-task-button">ADD TASK</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="task-list">
    </ul>
    <script src="to-do.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here JS

```
"use strict";
let ul = document.getElementById('task-list');
function loadtodos(){
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    if (data) {
        ul.innerHTML = data;
    }
}
loadtodos();
document.getElementById('add-task-button').addEventListener('click', function (){
    let input = document.querySelector('#input-task');
    let node = document.createElement("li");
    node.classList.add('tip');
    //mark complete/incomplete task
    let confirm = document.createElement('input');
        confirm.type = 'checkbox';
    node.appendChild(confirm);
    //task text
    let spanNode = document.createElement('span');//task text
        spanNode.classList.add('task');
        spanNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    node.appendChild(spanNode);
    //DELETE task
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
        deleteBtn.classList.add('delete-btn');
        deleteBtn.textContent = 'X';
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (){
           node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
           localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(ul.innerHTML));
        });
    node.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    //adding element to list
    document.getElementById('task-list').appendChild(node);
    //clear input
    document.getElementById('input-task').value=null;
    //saver
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(ul.innerHTML));
});
```

If I understand correctly I need a function outside of an 'add-task-button', I tried querySelector, but it removes only 1 line, and I don't quite understand how to remove it with querySelectorAll, because when I use it, buttons don't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is most likely you aren't finding the parent container with your delete parentNode reference.

For that delete button, you have 2 options. One is an adjustment to your code. You can find the container for the todo (the `li` tag) and remove that

```
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e){
       let parent = e.target.closest('li');
       parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
       localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(ul.innerHTML));
    });
```

The other is to set up a delegate event listener outside of the function, outside of the loop. It will work for all current and to-be-created delete buttons

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e){
       if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-btn')){
         let parent = e.target.closest('li');
         parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
         localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(ul.innerHTML));
       }
    });
```